# How to redirect with JQuery, load another page but sent some POST parameters in request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

How do I redirect using either JQuery, DOJO or plain JavaScript, load another page but sent some POST parameters in request?

Comment: Do you want to redirect the POST data too?

Comment: @primvdb Yes, need  POST data too

Answer (score 10):

This should work, but i haven't tested it:

```
function postData(url, data)
{
  var form = $('<form></form>');
  $(form).hide().attr('method','post').attr('action',url);
  for (i in data)
  {
    var input = $('<input type="hidden" />').attr('name',i).val(data[i]);
    $(form).append(input);
  }
  $(form).appendTo('body').submit();
}
```

Basically you can create a form on the fly and submit it. Unfortunately you can not POST stuff directly from script.

Comment: @Karan Just add action="_blank" attribute to the form:
$(form).hide().attr('method','post').attr('action',url).attr('target','_blank')

Comment: @Ivan Thanks buddy, this is just what I needed. One point though, if you wanna generate `input` names based on `data` value then you may pass an array of **json** in `data` variable like this: `var data = [{field_name: 'first_name', val: 'some user name'}, {field_name: 'last_name', val: 'This is last name'}]` then in for loop: `attr('name',data[i].field_name).val(data[i].val)`. Much handy and easy. Have a good day!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect with postdata using JavaScript, and I'm sure it's the same for jQuery as well. However, what you can do is...have a hidden form with post data, manipulate it as you need in javascript and submit that form.

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="mypage.php">
    <input id="myinput" type="hidden" value="mydata" /> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // in some function...
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do first the POST request to the page, and then redirect:

```
var urlToPost='http://www.example.com/';
$.post(urlToPost, {'PARAMETER':'VALUE', 'PARAMETER2': 'VALUE2' /*Etc.*/}, function(response){
/*Callback*/
alert(response);
document.location=urlToPost;
})
```

More info for this: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Voici ma proposition :

```
String.prototype.poster=function() 
{
    var requeteur=new XMLHttpRequest;
    requeteur.open('post',this,true); 
    requeteur.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    var equations=[]; 
    for(i in arguments) equations.push(arguments[i]);
    requeteur.send(equations.join(esper));
}
```

Au chargement, on récupère requeteur.responseText.

A vos commentaires !

Sacapuss

Comment: Please use English here.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```html
$().redirect('demo.php', {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'});
```