# asp.net hyperlink - click to make the POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlBanner" Target="_blank" style="padding-left:10px;" runat="server" ImageUrl="banner.png" />
```

I want to send some infomation such as FName, LName & Email into the POST request to another page ProcessInfo.aspx. This processing page pulls the values from the posted form like Request.Form["FName"]. I have to use only the POST technique, because i cannot make the changes to the ProcessInfo.aspx.

I cannot use the Querystring parameters to pass the info. I was hoping to use the WebRequest class to make the redirection to the second page.

How can i build the navigateURL property for making the POST request ?? Pls suggest. I am open to change the control also.

Comment: You can use session's to pass info.

Comment: On the receiving end , the values are retrieved using the form Request.Form["FName"] etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the easier way and is already present on stackOverflow.com

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440159/86023

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Request.Form Collection here is a good solution.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/desaijm/ASP.NetPostURL11282005005516AM/ASP.NetPostURL.aspx

Comment: It didn't work for me.. It is not doing the post. I tried changing the control to <asp:linkbutton> also.. but no luck.   <asp:LinkButton id="link1" runat="server" OnClick="link1_onclick">
                <img id="Img1" alt="image" src="/a/planner-side/images/contacts-feedback-survey-banner.png" />
            </asp:LinkButton>

Comment: In my case, i don't have the form fields to send the data. They are just some variable i need to pass to the second page using the POST..I think the example can only with input type submit button only. In my case, it is an image..

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to call `ProcessInfo.aspx`.

If you have the inputs FName, LName & Email on your current page, you will receive the values you ProcessInfo page too.