# saving file generated by TCPDF

Tags: php, jquery, tcpdf

I'd like to generate and open PDF when user clicks on a button. Here is my code so far:

index.php:

```
</html>
<head>
<script>
$('.cmd_butt').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'create_pdf.php',
    data: {id: $(this).attr('order_id'), name: $(this).attr('name')},
    type: 'post'
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="cmd_butt" order_id="250" name="pdf_but">Download PDF</button>
</body>
</html>
```

create_pdf.php:

```
<?php

//header('Content-type: application/pdf')
header("Content-type: application-download");
//header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyPDF.pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
// some code
// some code

//$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
//$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'FD');
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

How can I open a new window with generated PDF? Or notify user with "save as" dialog to download this PDF? I've tried different Output() combinations but none of them worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [POST to server, receive PDF, deliver to user w/ jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186562/post-to-server-receive-pdf-deliver-to-user-w-jquery)

Comment: not a duplicate. The post doesn't explain how to open a new window with PDF

Comment: jQuery `.ajax` will not redirect, you may need to use `GET` method, or create a dummy form, and then submit

Comment: If you want to create a dummy form, you can refer this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6440159/1877620

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax can only fetch textual data, it can't show the PDF directly or in a new window (from response).

You need to either submit form instead of AJAX, or create a file from ajax call and in response, gets a response about creation of file. e.g. created file name, and than open a new window based on that.

Comment: In that case, how do I dispose of PDF file after user has downloaded it?

Comment: Just submit form and use the method mentioned by Basant. in this case the file is not created on File system, so no need to worry about dispose.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this

```
$pdf->Output('yourfilename.pdf','D');
```

This will prompt the user to choose where to save the PDF file.

Comment: Thank you SO much! I didn't want to have to save to server. I already had a page generating a pdf using TCPDF...but at the end of my script I was using 'I' instead of 'D'. The simple change to 'D' worked!

Comment: @Webgrity This throws error `TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: ../invoice_job_6.pdf`

Comment: @RNKushwaha try using an absolute path for the file.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<button class="cmd_butt" order_id="250" name="pdf_but">Download PDF</button>
```

to

```
<a href="create_pdf.php?order_id=250" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
```

Remove the java in *index.php*
Remove the headers in *create_pdf.php*