# TCPDF Filename Issue

Tags: php, tcpdf

In php when I download the pdf file, I want the PDF file name to be downloaded with a name something like this **simon (07-10-2015).pdf**

Thank you

Comment: The must be generated somewhere!!

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978191/saving-file-generated-by-tcpdf

Comment: are you asking about tcpdf??then you can directly change in that `$pdf->Output('anyname.pdf', 'I');`

Answer (score 2):

TRy THis

```
ob_start();    
$file           =   '';//pdf path here
    downloadFile($file,'simon (07-10-2015).pdf','text/plain');
    function downloadFile($file, $name, $mime_type='')
    {
     if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');
     $size = filesize($file);
     $name = rawurldecode($name);
     $known_mime_types=array(
        "pdf" => "application/pdf",
        "txt" => "text/plain",
        "html" => "text/html",
        "htm" => "text/html",
        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
        "zip" => "application/zip",
        "doc" => "application/msword",
        "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
        "png" => "image/png",
        "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
        "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
        "php" => "text/plain"
     );
     if($mime_type==''){
         $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
         if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
            $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
         } else {
            $mime_type="application/force-download";
         };
     };
     @ob_end_clean(); 
     if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
      ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

     header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
     header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
     header("Cache-control: private");
     header('Pragma: private');
     header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

     if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
     {
        list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
        list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
        list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
        $range=intval($range);
        if(!$range_end) {
            $range_end=$size-1;
        } else {
            $range_end=intval($range_end);
        }
        $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: $new_length");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
     } else {
        $new_length=$size;
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
     }
     $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
     $bytes_send = 0;
     if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
     {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        fseek($file, $range);

        while(!feof($file) && 
            (!connection_aborted()) && 
            ($bytes_send<$new_length)
              )
        {
            $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
            print($buffer);
            flush();
            $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
        }
     fclose($file);
     } else
     die('Error - can not open file.');
    die();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks For your respond. That works but the file is unreadable after downloaded.

But i got the solution in another way, I just had to change small snippet in tcpdf library.

if ($dest[0] != 'F') {
        $name = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', '_', $name);
 $name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]/', '', $name);
} 

you just have to comment the above code. It will take the name as u pass.

Thanks any way..